# What exactly is singular about a singular p-symplex?

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, simplex

A so-called singular $p$-symplex in an $n$-manifold is defined to be a differentiable map

$$
\sigma_p: \Delta_p \rightarrow M^n
$$

where $\Delta_p = (P_0,P_1, \ldots,P_p)$ is a standard $p$-simplex given by its $p+1$ vertices.

It is said that there are no restrictions on the rank of the map $\sigma_p$, so if I understand it correctly it does not necessarily have to be singular.

So what exactly is singular about a singular $p$-simplex then?

Comment: I reckon it's just to reinforce the idea that $\sigma$ need not be injective.

Comment: Sometimes, $M$ has a triangulation, i.e. is made by gluing simplices. The homology can be defined using these simplices has a base of the space of chains. Singular simplices are much more general objects, and form a base of an infinite dimensional space of "singular chains".

Comment: I think you should view the word "singular" as meaning "not necessarily regular" and not as meaning "non-regular" in this context.